# how to retrieve the variable of an object stored in localStorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

how to recover for example the `us_firstname` of my object stored in `LocalStorage` ?

```
 studentInfos() {
    this.eleveService.apiGetEleveInfo(this.token, this.us_id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {

        this.student = data.results[0]

        localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(data));

        console.log('student', this.student)

      })
  }
```

[the strucutre of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TokhW.jpg)

Comment: Provide the object structure as text, not as an image or link to one.

Comment: Actually, you are storing the entire data. Instead of it, try to store student object and try.
 localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(this.student));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const student = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("student"))[0]

Comment: yes it works , but i just can not get the contact us_firstname (see photo please) , i need also to recover the us_firstname from contact to display it in my html...

Comment: make a console.log(student) after, and see what are you getting

Answer (score 0):

You can get your localstorage value using below:

The getItem() method returns value of the specified Storage Object item.

```
let student = localStorage.getItem("student");

// convert this to object
student = JSON.parse(student);
```

Comment: yes it works , but i just can not get the contact us_firstname (see photo please) , i need also to recover the us_firstname from contact to display it in my html...

Comment: @NahmanPks, Actually, you are storing the entire data. Instead of it, try to store student object and try. localStorage.setItem("student", JSON.stringify(this.student));

If you are storing entire data, after retriving it, again u need to initilize the student correctly.